# How do I link buttons to a text box in QtGui?

Tags: python

I am making a multiple choice quiz. I have made the buttons and a text box with the questions and a text box with the possible answers. How would I connect the buttons to the answer as to move on to the next question?

Here is my code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class  Ui_MainWindow(object):


       def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)

        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        #Text Display Window
        self.textDisp = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.textDisp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 381, 71))
        self.textDisp.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textDisp.setObjectName("textDisp")
        self.textDisp.append('Question 1:')
        self.textDisp.append('What is ... ?')

        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 171, 80))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")

        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        self.textDisp2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.textDisp2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 381, 71))
        self.textDisp2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textDisp2.setObjectName("textDisp2")
        self.textDisp2.append('A: ...')
        self.textDisp2.append('B: ...')
        self.textDisp2.append('C: ...')
        self.textDisp2.append('D: ...')

        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 171, 80))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")

        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
##
##        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
##        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 171, 80))
##        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
##
##        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
##        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
##        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

##        #Label for Answer 1
##        self.ans1 = QtGui.QLabel()
##        self.ans1.setObjectName("answer1")
##        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.addWidget(self.ans1)
##
##        #Input for Answer 1
##        self.ans1Input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
##        self.ans1Input.setObjectName("answer1Input")
##        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.addWidget(self.ans1Input)

        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2 = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(219, 90, 171, 80))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")

##        #Label for Answer 2
##        self.answer2 = QtGui.QLabel()
##        self.answer2.setObjectName("number2")
##        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.addWidget(self.answer2)
##
##        #Input for Answer 2
##        self.ans2Input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
##        self.ans2Input.setObjectName("numb2Input")
##        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.addWidget(self.ans2Input)

        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 180, 381, 80))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        #Button for Option A
        self.abtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.abtn.setObjectName("abtn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.abtn, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.abtn.setText("A")

##        self.abtn.clicked.connect(self.)

        #Button for Option B
        self.bbtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.bbtn.setObjectName("bbtn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bbtn, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.bbtn.setText("B")

##        self.bbtn.clicked.connect(self.)

        #Button for Option C
        self.cbtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.cbtn.setObjectName("cbtn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.cbtn, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.cbtn.setText("C")

##        self.cbtn.clicked.connect(self.)

        #Button for Option D
        self.dbtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.dbtn.setObjectName("dbtn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.dbtn, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.dbtn.setText("D")

##        self.dbtn.clicked.connect(self.)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What should happen after the user pressed the associated answer button for the question? Do you want to highlight the selected answer or somehow give feedback to the user to confirm which answer they selected? would the answer get saved in the app somewhere before moving on to the next question? This seems very doable, but not sure how you want to do it. any further details would be helpful.

Comment: davedwards, I want it to displayh the correct answer and move on to the next question